# check when the object hits canvas border and do other animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

The object is moving away from the top center angle of 60° downwards and to the left. When it reaches the edge of canvas It appears at the opposite edge of the same height / distance and keeps moving in the same direction to center top.
So what I have so far is first part, move down to left, what I need to do is to:

1) Check when it hits canvas border.
2) Transform to opposite side at the same height and distance. 
3) Move to start position.

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
var x = 0,
  y = 0;

function draw() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + 135, y + 15); //50
  ctx.lineTo(x + 135, y + 80);
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'orange';
  ctx.moveTo(x + 105, y + 20);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + 135, y + 5, x + 135, y + 5, x + 165, y + 20);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x + 165, y + 20, 15, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x + 165, y + 60, 20, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x + 165, y + 20, 10, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#7CFC00";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x + 165, y + 60, 15, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#458B00";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
  ctx.moveTo(x + 165, y + 5);
  ctx.lineTo(x + 165, y + 80);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  x = x - 2;
  y = y + 1.5;
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(34,45,23,0.4)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  //ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height);
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Probably I need to include some if-else statements to check x and y, but I did and it didn't show anything, would appreciate your help.

Comment: So i did, part 2 and part3, but how to stop animation when it hits certain coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Asteroids style wrap around

I am assuming you need a asteroids style wrap around. This means that the image must be drawn up to four times, top and bottom, left and right, and on occasion bottom right to top left.

To simplify the rendering I draw your log onto an image and then just draw that image rather than the whole rendering process every time. Its much quicker.

If you want the animation to stop at some point then you need to do a test of the coordinates.

I have added a box to the canvas. When the top left of the logo is inside this box the animation will end. Takes about 4 times from horizontal wrap around to hit the box. You can of course put the box anywhere and make it any size.

```js
// function creates a canvas and adds a context 
var createImage=function(w,h){var i=document.createElement("canvas");i.width=w;i.height=h;i.ctx=i.getContext("2d");return i;}

// renders the logo to ctx;
function createLogo(ctx) {
var x = - 105;
var y = 0;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x + 135, y + 15); //50
ctx.lineTo(x + 135, y + 80);
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'orange';
ctx.moveTo(x + 105, y + 20);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + 135, y + 5, x + 135, y + 5, x + 165, y + 20);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x + 165, y + 20, 15, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI, true);
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x + 165, y + 60, 20, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI, true);
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x + 165, y + 20, 10, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI, true);
ctx.fillStyle = "#7CFC00";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x + 165, y + 60, 15, 0.5 * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI, true);
ctx.fillStyle = "#458B00";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
ctx.moveTo(x + 165, y + 5);
ctx.lineTo(x + 165, y + 80);
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(34,45,23,0.4)";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);

}

// Main animation loop
function mainLoop1(time){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h); // clear da screen

x += dx + w;  // Always keep in positive coordinates.
y += dy + h;
x %= w;  // use modulo to move from one side of screen to other
y %= h;

// check for extra draws
if(x > w - logo.width){  // does sthe x wrap around?
    ctx.drawImage(logo, x - w, y); // yes draw
    if(y > h - logo.height){  // does y wrap around 
        ctx.drawImage(logo, x - w, y - h); // then this is wraped from bottom right
                                      // to top left
    }
}
if(y > h - logo.height){  // check for bottom top wrap around.
    ctx.drawImage(logo, x, y - h);
}
ctx.drawImage(logo, x, y);  // draw normal

// is top left of logo inside home box?
if(x > homeX && x < homeX + homeSize && y > homeY && y < homeY + homeSize){
     return; // animation done so stop here.
}
ctx.filStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeRect(homeX, homeY, homeSize, homeSize);

requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop1);


}    
// create canvas and add to DOM
var canvas = createImage(512,196);
canvas.style.border = "1px black solid";
var ctx = canvas.ctx;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Create image to hold rendered logo as the image will need to be drawn sometime 4 times
// and this will help improve render performance.
const logo = createImage(82,82)
createLogo(logo.ctx);

// x,y position
// dx,dy x and y speed
// w,h = canvas w and height
var x,y,dx,dy,w,h, homeX, homeY, homeSize;
x = 200;
y = 0;
dx = -2;
dy = 1.5;
w = canvas.width;
h = canvas.height;
homeX = 100;
homeY = 30;
homeSize = 10;

// start the animation
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop1);
```